# Report deployment using rs.exe generate unauthorized issue

Tags: report

Recently I've worked on the report deployment using rs.exe. There is http status 401: unauthorized stopping me. 
What i did

1. installed sql server 2012 and report server 2008 on the Windows Server 2008 vm machine
2. configured the report server with parameters
   a. Use built-in account: Network service
   b. For the web service URL, IP Address: All Assigned, Port: 80, the URL is http://:80/ReportServer
   c. same setting used to the manager URL, it is http://:80/Reports
3. For testing, i turned off firewall, deleted the default site in IIS.
4. created a sample report
5. deployed it using a batch file which calls rs.exe

The first issue I have seen. After the step 2, i clicked the test link of either web service URL or the manager URL in Reporting Service Configuration Manager. The result is

"ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: 
http://..com/Reports

Unable to determine IP address from host name ..com
The DNS server returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
..."

I am not sure why and how .com is appended to the domain name.

The second issue is that I ran the below command line locally

```
rs.exe -i PublishSampleReports.rss -s http://localhost:80/ReportServer -e Mgmt2010 -v reportName=<MyReportName> -t
```

the command worked fine, which can deploy the report. 
However, if i replaced localhost using the ip address, and using the username and password, i got http status 401: Unauthorized issue. For example,

```
rs.exe -i PublishSampleReports.rss -s http://<xxx.xxx.xx.xx>:80/ReportServer -u <username> -p <password> -e Mgmt2010 -v reportName=<MyReportName> -t
```

Meanwhile, I can see the client ip and username in http log file when i used 'localhost'. On the other hand, there is no such ip and username in the log file when i used the ip address. I can access the report web service via web browser using localhost and the ip address. 
I am not sure why there is unauthorized issue there? Would you guys advice me what i missed, please?

Comment: I figured them out. The reason is the server is located in the different domain, and also we are using proxy environment. All requests from the client will go to the server via the proxy machine